# How to replace the following code in Java 8

Tags: lambda, java-8

I would like to use **Java 8 feature** for the following code but I could not find a solution

```java
if(attribute != null){
  for(AttributeValue aValue : attribute.getValue()){
    if(aValue.getAttributeType().equalsIgnoreCase("Select")){
      AttributeOption aOption = service.getAttributeOption(accessToken, value.getId())
      aOption.setAttributeCode(aValue.getCode());
      optionList.add(aOption);
    }
  }
}
```

I do not know if the code is better, more readable in Java 8 but I have to use it in Java 8.

Comment: Hint: Java 8 is not a new language. All the code you have written in Java 5, 6 or 7 is still valid Java 8 code.

Comment: I guess he meant Java 8 streaming API.

Comment: @fiveelements , yeah Streaming API with lamba expressions. I know ifPresent method for Optional but it is not applicable in this case, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using streaming API with lambda expression:

```
attributeList.stream().filter(attribute -> attribute.getAttributeType().equals("Select"))
                    .map(attribute -> new AttributeOption(attribute.getCode())).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

We are filtering AttributeValue objects by type and then mapping those to create AttributeOption objects.

You may refer to the full running code [from github](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/java/misc/src/main/java/org/openapex/samples/misc/stack/StreamingAPI57152335.java)

Comment: Can we add attribute null check to the line?? for example; Optional.ofNullable(attribute).map(item -> attributeList).stream().......

Comment: Yes. You can do like `Optional.ofNullable(attributeList).map(Collection::stream).orElseGet(Stream::empty).filter(attribute -> attribute.getAttributeType().equals("Select"))
                .map(attribute -> new AttributeOption(attribute.getCode())).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @Eric the answer was marked as accepted. After I modified the answer to add the code link the acceptance is removed. Would you mind to add it back?

Comment: Thank you for your effort but you did not use attribute variable. That's why I took it back.

Comment: You made an example about it in detail on your page, I appreciate it.